# how to execute a code before another in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute a loading before click on a div block.
actually, the code is like this:

```
$("#bookmark").click(function() {
$("#page-loader").fadeIn("slow"); //should execute first

//my second code witch is hiding and showing some elements and takes about 5 sec to do
$(elements).hide() or show();
});
```

but when user clicks, it first executes second, then first :/

i've tried delay(), setTimeout ... but non of them worked :(

**Edit**: It worked guys, thanks all.you know i'm a really beginner and don't understand too much from those docs :))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From documentation: http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

Second parameter of fadeIn function is a callback `.fadeIn( [duration ] [, complete ] )` you can put there code you want to execute after animation.

```
$("#page-loader").fadeIn("slow", function() {
    $(elements).hide(); // or show();
});
```

Answer (score 4):

Because `fadeIn` is an asynchronous operation.  Execute the follow-up operations in its callback:

```
$("#page-loader").fadeIn("slow", function () {
    $(elements).hide()// or show();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Look for http://api.jquery.com/fadein/

```
.fadeIn( [duration ] [, complete ] )

$("#bookmark").click(function() {
    $("#page-loader").fadeIn("slow", function complete() {
        $(elements).hide();
        //$(elements).show();
    });
});
```